# HTTP Post Connection Guarantee

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, http-post

I have an application that speaks to a server on a regular basis using HTTP POST. I am trying to make the connection as failsafe as possible, so the application will not try to send a thing if it does not have a working data connection. How can I detect a connection loss during the middle of a `NSURLConnection`? The timeout does not work without a minimum time of 240, so that is out of the question. I could use an `NSTimer`, but it still hangs because the `NSURLConnection` seems to take up the main thread not allowing any changes. Some sort of delgate maybe?

My code is as follows:

```
-(NSData*) postData: (NSString*) strData //it's gotta know what to post, nawmean?
{    
    //postString is the STRING TO BE POSTED
    NSString *postString;

    //this is the string to send
    postString = @"data=";
    postString = [postString stringByAppendingString:strData]; 

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"MYSERVERURLHERE"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]];

    //setting prarameters of the POST connection
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request addValue:@"en-US" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Language"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //[request setTimeoutInterval:10.0];

    NSLog(@"%@",postString);

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    NSLog(@"Starting the send!");
    //this sends the information away. everybody wave!
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Just finished receiving!");

    if (urlData == nil)
    {
         if (&error)
         {
         NSLog(@"ERROR");
         NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR"];
         urlData = [errorString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         }
    }

    return urlData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure your main thread is blocked when using `sendSynchronousRequest:`. That is very bad practice for if the user loses the internet connection, the UI will be completely out of order. Apple writes in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Important: Because this call can potentially take several minutes to
>   fail (particularly when using a cellular network in iOS), you should
>   never call this function from the main thread of a GUI application.**

I strongly advise to use the asynchronous methods `connectionWithRequest:delegate:`. You can easily catch the interruption in `connection:didFailWithError:`.

Believe me, it's not that hard, but well worth the effort.

Comment: Can you point to a tutorial of sorts? I'm not familiar with asynchronous methods.

Comment: Check out my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420837/how-to-download-docx-pdf-image-pptx-or-any-file-from-a-internet/) question. It is the shortest possible tutorial...