# XCode iphone programming: sending a URL string parsed from an xml file via segue to be loaded in UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, nsxmlparser, segue

I'm creating an iphone application where 2 URLs are passed from an xml file and sent from a UITableView to a detail view through a segue to be loaded in a UIImageView.
This is my prepareForSegue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detail"]) {
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
         NSMutableString *imgURL1 = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"imageURL1"];
         [[segue destinationViewController] setImg1:imgURL1];
         //img1 is declared in the detailviewcontroller class
    }
}
```

And this is my viewDidLoad in the detailViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL * imageURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:self.img1];
    NSData * imageData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL1];
    UIImage * imag1e = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData1];
    appImage1.image = imag1e;
    //appImage1 is also declared in the detailViewController class
}
```

Now the problem is that when i run the app nothing is displayed in the appImage1 and no error or bug is reported.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Is `appImage1` set from the storyboard? Is it actually set? Also, not a great idea to use `dataWithContentsOfURL` on the main thread.

Comment: yes it is set from the storyboard

Comment: And you debugged to check that `feeds` actually contains what you think it does and where you think it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems here:

1) Why mutable string? `NSString` is enough.

2) It is not really safe to rely on the "selected row". That is just a side effect of picking a row. Ideally, you should use the sender.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)sender];
```

3) Don't call the URL load on the main thread. Rather, use an asynchronous loading with `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection`.  Set the image in the `didFinishLoading` callback.

4) Check what else could have gone wrong:

- the image view is nil.
- the string is nil.
- The URL is nil or invalid.
- the server is not responding or not sending data or taking too long.

Comment: can you send me an example on how to use asynchronous loading in my case?

Comment: Sure. Look at my code in the answer for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7421584/427083) question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. 
Apparently, the problem was with the URL. The xml parser was storing the url in the url variable with a space in the beginning so all I had to do is to use stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet so the segue method looks like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

//sends the image link
    NSString *imageURLS = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"appImageURL"];
    imageURLS = [imageURLS stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSURL *img = [NSURL URLWithString: imageURLS];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setAppImageURL:img];
}
```

Comment: You should accept my answer because it included this possible error and it obviously helped you. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: You did not accept the answer yet. You have to click the checkmark underneath the vote number of my answer. Welcome to StackOverflow!