# MPMoviePlayer play from protected url play Stream

Tags: ios, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to play a video that is hosted on my server. I've been looking around for awhile and I haven't solved the problem. I am trying to use NSURLCredential.

Here is my Code:

```
-(MPMoviePlayerController *)moviePlayerController
{
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ABCd.com/secret/MOVIE.mov"];

     NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc]
                               initWithUser: @"username"
                               password: @"password"
                               persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

     NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                         initWithHost: [url host]
                                         port: 80
                                         protocol: [url scheme]
                                         realm: nil
                                         authenticationMethod: NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic];
     [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage]
     setDefaultCredential: credential
     forProtectionSpace: protectionSpace];

     _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
}
```

When using moviePlayerBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification 
I get the following error

Did finish with error: Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-1013 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (MediaPlayerErrorDomain error -1013.)"

Any Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you confirmed that you have made a successful connection and have been granted access?

Comment: Yes I have confirmed a successful connection.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
realm: nil
```

try using

```
realm: [url host]
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I still get an error _itemFailedToPlayToEnd:{kind =1; new = 2; old = 0;}

Comment: Take a look at this previous SO posting. Try running the test code in the accepted answer and see if you can download a simple text file. If it works for you then you can eliminate the NSURLCredential connection and downloading not working issue at least. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420837/how-to-download-docx-pdf-image-pptx-or-any-file-from-a-internet

Comment: I tried this I can download a simple file. I don't understand where to go from here.

Comment: This sounds like a hard nut to crack. You have to try to eliminate all possibilities here. Try downloading the same movie file from a non protected realm on your server. If it works then you know the movie file is good and your MPMoviePlayerController code is also good.

Comment: I can stream the video from the non protected url. I can download the video then play it, but I want to stream it, I think it will be better for the user.

Comment: If it's a large file, I agree. honestly I am kinda out of ideas. Perhaps the issue is not your code but something in your server but that's beyond my knowledge. Take a look at this link. It deals with streaming a video. You can adjust the code to include your NSURLCredential. If that fails I suggest you repost your question to include streaming in the title. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194776/how-to-play-a-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller

Comment: I just updated the question hopefully this will help.

Comment: Repost the updated question as new so it gets some front line exposure and make sure to include EVERYTHING you have tried so you don't get people giving you the same suggestions I already have. Good luck and hang in there!

Comment: Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162404/stream-large-movie-with-credential-through-mpmovieplayer